# How do I make webpack continue to watch after the first change?

Tags: webpack

When I run `webpack --progress --colors --watch` as specified by the webpack docs webpack will successfully watch my directory for changes and bundle successfully when I make a change to a file. However I have to run the command again to get it to watch again which in a way defeats the purpose of watching in the first place. How do I get webpack to continue watching after the first change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got into this problem: [webpack issue #2297](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2297#issuecomment-260703995) as suggested in this problem, try adding `-d` option and see if that helps.

If you are interested what `-d` option does, in webpack's help it says `shortcut for --debug --devtool sourcemap --output-pathinfo`.